# Creating Visual Studio Template - config values depend on project name

Tags: c#, .net, templates, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I make visual studio templates fo my projects/solutions.
Is there any way to change some text in config/code depend on what somebody name this project?

Thanks for help
apukineimakiapudjuh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$safeprojectname$` parameter.  See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa(v=vs.100).aspx) for the parameters that are available, and [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky(v=vs.100).aspx) for a more general overview.